# Update value in a loop in perl

Tags: perl, loops, ubuntu

What i wanted to do is the perl code will read from the configuration file and print in an infinite loop. After i change the value in the configuration file, the value in the loop displayed on the terminal will also be updated. Can somebody help me on how to this?

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use CGI;
use Config::Tiny;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

$| = 1;

# Write some data to the client
my $file = "/home/gentoo/config.conf";

my $Config = Config::Tiny->read($file);

my $status_in_file = $Config->{"offline_online_status"}->{"offline_online_status.offline_online_state"};
my $status_mode = $Config->{"data_silence_mode"}->{"data_silence_mode.data_silence_mode"};


while (1) {
    sleep 5;
    print "$status_in_file\n";
print "$status_mode\n";
}
```

The terminal only prints the first run value but not the updated value. it will only display this:

```
online
disabled
online
disabled
online
disabled
```

But when i change the value in the configuration file from "online" to "offline", the terminal still prints like the above. How to make it to be updated if i change the value from the configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put that `Config::Tiny->read()` in your `while(1) { ... }`, do something like this:

```
while (1) {
    my $Config = Config::Tiny->read($file);

    my $status_in_file = $Config->{"offline_online_status"}->{"offline_online_status.offline_online_state"};
    my $status_mode = $Config->{"data_silence_mode"}->{"data_silence_mode.data_silence_mode"};

    print "$status_in_file\n";
    print "$status_mode\n";

    sleep 5;
}
```

Comment: Okay. i saw my problem there. I didn't put the read process into the loop. Thanks dude! You saved my day today. :) @leeduhem